# minimal delay between input and output possible to implement in FPGA

Tags: fpga

I am trying to find out how fast can I get the transition of a digital 500MHz signal from FPGA input to it's output. The delay will need to be adjusted, but that's a different task. For now I just need to know if I could make it around 4-8 ns.

FPGA is not chosen yet, probably one from Altera. Need to find a suitable one.

Comment: similar question to "how fast can you drive from one side of town to the other side?"

Comment: Read the FPGA datasheet. (You did not even mention which FPGA family).

Comment: I am still able to choose the town/FPGA to drive throw. The country/manufacturer of it's origin is Altera.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to find out, is to pick an FPGA you like (e.g. based on cost and size), and compile a simple design in the FPGA vendors toolkit.

You could take a piece of code as simple as:

```
module a (input b, output c);
    assign c = b;
endmodule
```

Pick to pins that would be in useful places for what you need. Then compile the design. You can then run timing analysis to find out exactly what delay the toolkit suggests the path with take under different temperature and silicon performance corners.

You can simplify the timing analysis by creating a design constraints (e.g. SDC for Intel FPGA) and specifying the delay target for the net. The fitter will then try its very best to meet the requirements, telling you if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the FPGA you're using. What you're looking for is called the propagation delay, so time a signal needs to pass a LUT. Then you have the distinction between internal and external propagation delay.
The propagation delay usually is the range of a few ns and the external is slightly bigger than the internal.

Here's an example from a Lattice ICE Datasheet

[image]

Comment: looked through Arria 10 datasheet, didn't find such info. thanx for the tip, I will examine other FPGA for this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you have to read data_sheet of different FPGA's, and after than choosing the best choice(cost, size and etc are of course important) you can write your code on the vendor's toolkit and check the synthesis, translation, place and route reports and find out the best frequency you can apply to design.